# Select Checkboxes when click menu item

Tags: android, android-activity

When I press "select all" i want to checked all check boxes which have every listview item it is my layout::

[image]

```
enter code here
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {

        case R.id.mark_all:
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this code selects only one checkbox which has first listview item.thank you

Comment: can you also add the layout xml please.

Comment: its not working :/ it selects first item also :( i have custom adapter for listview,and in my item is checkbox

Answer (score 0):

**Use a for loop to get all the checkboxes**

**here an example:**

```
boolean check = lv.isItemChecked(0);
for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    lv.setItemChecked(i, !check);
```

Answer (score 0):

use for loop and get the view which contains check box:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listview.getChildCount(); i++)
{
   View v = listview.getChildAt(i);    

   CheckBox ch = v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
   ch.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: its not working :/ it selects first item also :( i have custom adapter for listview,and in my item is checkbox

Comment: then listview.getChildAt(i) will return check box.

Comment: I can not add my code,i have custom listview adapter and in my item i have checkbox

Answer (score 0):

first add SparseBooleanArray in your class

```
SparseBooleanArray mChecked = new SparseBooleanArray();
```

now add this function to check:
if check is true than :all item checked 
size = no of list vew item

```
public void setAllChecked(boolean check) {
    int size = getCount();
    if (check) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            mChecked.put(i, true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            mChecked.put(i, false);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

now before returning the view check the check box status

```
CheckbixID.setChecked((mChecked.get(position) == true ? true : false));
```

Comment: size = no of list vew item,what size do you mean?

Comment: sorry but i don't understand where can i get CheckboxID.thank you